# C# Process Monitoring Application That Is Not a Child Process

Tags: c#, process

I have a solution of several Windows Forms applications. I also have a SQL Server. I created an app that is meant to show us who is using one of our applications and what machine they are on by uploading the name of the app, user name, path to the executable they launched, and date / time it launched to a table in the SQL Server.

The user starts one of our apps. We will call it the parent app. The parent app starts the WhoIsLoggedIn.exe app and passes the process ID of the parent app to it. The WhoIsLoggedIn app, uploads the info to the SQL Server and then periodically checks to see if the parent process is running. When it is no longer running, the WhoIsLoggedIn app runs a DELETE query to to delete the previously inserted record from the table.

The problem is that the WhoIsLoggedIn app is a child of the parent app in the process tree, so if a user clicks End Task in the task manager, both apps end immediately and the WhoIsLoggedIn app doesn't have a chance to DELETE the record from the SQL Server table. If the user closes the parent app normally (or by End Process), then as soon as the WhoIsLoggedIn app notices that the parent process is no longer running, it runs a DELETE query to remove the User / Parent App record from the SQL Server table.

Before anyone brings it up, due to STIG's, we do not have access to the command prompt, so I cannot use CMD to start the WhoIsLoggedIn application.

Are there other ways to do this besides say, creating a service that watches for our apps?

I have tried setting ShellExecute to both True and False, but that didn't work. I tried starting the process from Program.cs and from the parent application Form_Load event, and nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: If using windows service not going to work, then, there are - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20533/How-to-know-when-the-Task-Manager-kills-your-app - it "spans" second process to watch your "parent app". If that is not acceptable, you can try "hook" into listening for ExitProcess notification (example -> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed).

Comment: Thanks @yob. I will check both of those links.